# Using batch command to rename a file's extension after the file is closed

Tags: batch-file

I have 2 batch files, and for ease of understanding, let's call them X and Y. When X is run, it will turn Y into a text file by renaming its extension, then open Y for edit, along with Y's containing folder so I can change Y back in to a batch file when I'm done.

Here's the code:

```
@echo off
ren "D:\Batch CMD\Y.bat" "Y.txt"

START "" "D:\Batch CMD"
timeout /t 1

START /wait D:\"Batch CMD"\"Y.txt"
exit
```

I want to automate the change-back-to-batch process by having X stays active, then rename Y's extension after it detects Y has been closed.

I tried to put it on a timer, but it's too unreliable since I don't know how long I'll be editing Y.

Is there another way to do that?

Comment: Notepad y.txt. X.bat will not proceed until notepad is closed. Regardless of that you do not need to do the rename to edit the file. You can just do notepad y.bat

Comment: Thanks, I'll try it out.